Gears sometimes become tight and sometimes slip
Description:
I have made a gearbox to increase torque of a motor.
I have used 2 spur gears(metal gears) one is smaller(driver) and other is larger(driven). I have mounted these gears into a metal box. The shaft is connected to ball bearings to reduce friction.
Now when I rotate these gears by hand, in one full rotation of the big gear, half of the time the big gear is hard to move and feels like the gears are crushing each other and the rest of the time the 2 gears slip and the distance between them increases.
What could be the reason for this? From my point of view, even if both the gears (and hence the shaft on which they are attached) are not parallel to each other,it should be either hard to rotate all the time or the gears should slip all the times. It does not makes sense to me that the gears are tight half the times and slip the rest of time (in one full rotation).
Any information relating to the problem would be of great help as I do not have much idea of mechanical engineering. Better tags suggestion for this question would also be helpful.
NOTE: I have not used any kind of lubricants between the gears. Would using thick grease help with this issue?
EDIT 1:
Big Gear:

Small Gear:

Gear Box:


your gears are probably not correctly centered.  Look for runout as each gear is spun on the shaft.

please add a picture of the gears

@TigerGuy Runout means the path traced by the outer edge of the gear as it rotates? How would that be of any help?

@jsotola have added pictures, removed background for clarity.

how are those pictures showing a problem with meshing?

@ you need image of assembled gearbox,, specifically the part where the 2 gears contact each other?

@jsotola added image of assembled gearbox.

runout indicates that the gear in eccentric, meaning more mesh on one side of the rotation.

I suspect the shaft of the big gear is bent.

@GregLocock that definitely wont be the case because I have made 4 such gear box and all have same problem.

The hole in one of the gears may be eccentric. Or a gear may be cast poorly and not meshing properly on one side. You should be able to figure this out easily if you take the gears out and examine them.

@Drew The big gear does seems eccentric. Any solution to this? Would applying Grade 2 grease help?
